# image upload and image.ContentLenght > 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have object street which have some photos. I'm trying to implement upload on the same form as where creating new street object. So image a mvc web form with fields

- StreetName
- StreetNumber
- Photo1
- Photo2
- Photo3

Now, on the create.cshtml page I have form with `StreetName` and `StreetNumber` fields and

```
<input type="file" name="postedImages" />
<input type="file" name="postedImages" />
<input type="file" name="postedImages" />
```

On submiting this form I'm sending these data to the StreetController for further process

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(StreetViewModel newData, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> postedImages)
 {
    //create object and save stretname and streetnumber
    //process posted images
    foreach(var image in postedImages)
    {
        //this is where error occured if I post only one or two images from my view
       if(image.ContentLength >0)
       {
          //process and save images
       }
    }

 }
```

As you can read inside my commented lines if I post exact number of images that are provided on the web form everything is fine, but If I send 1 or 2 images error occured.

How to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `null` check before accessing the `ContentLength` proeprty

```
if((image!=null) && (image.ContentLength >0))
{
      //process and save images
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`foreach(var image in postedImages.Where(pi => pi != null))`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
If(image != null)
    if(image.ContentLength > 0)
        {
           //code
        }
```

Check if its null before you are getting a property, this is the reason for the error.